# Integrating Images with MDG Technology in Enterprise Architect

Tags: image, uml, enterprise-architect

I have a problem with importing images into MDG technology of my custom toolbox.

In other words, I designed my own toolbox in EA using MDG technology. The toolbox has about 80 images of a network topology which represent images for each element in the toolbox.

The problem is when I am trying to generate MDG technology and I choose different XML resources of my implementation such as profile, toolbox, diagram, and images. I noticed that not all images are available in my MDG package except some of them, as is shown in the following figure.

[image]

AS I mentioned before the images exceed 80 ones and only 12 images are available in my package. I think the size of images is the problem because I replaced the bigger size of images with smaller ones I found more images are selected in my MDG package but still not all of them.

I want to integrate all these images with my implremnation, but I waste a lot of time for solving that problem.

How I can integrate all of these images with my MDG design, and if the problem is exactly the size of the images, how I can solve it??

Note that: the total size of all images is 570 KB in Metafile Extension (.WMF)

Comment: As you describe it I would recommend to send a bug report.